# How to preserve user-uploaded files on WebDeploy in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

In the Azure release definition I publish the build artifact to the UAT WebApp using Azure web deploy. However this deletes any previously user-uploaded files (e.g. images).

How can I release to UAT and preserve the user uploaded files?

Do I somehow need to perform the equivalent of extracting the .zip file over the existing files rather than replacing the entire website directory with the contents of the .zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following MSBuild property to your build

```
 /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true
```

OR add the MSDeploy provider flag:

```
-enableRule:DoNotDelete
```

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/01/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-keep-existing-files-during-deployment/

Comment: Both this answer and Julien's answers are correct. I ended up using this answer for my scenario. You can now do this using the GUI in the Azure Web Deployment section of build/release configuration in Visual Studio online.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the -skip:Directory option to excluse the directory where the images are uploaded ? See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(WS.10).aspx